# Javascript parameter not well executed when contain space or specific character

Tags: php, javascript, firefox

The problem is when the link is clicked. I have a problem ONLY if the third parameter contain space OR/AND character like ê,é,î...

```
<a href="javascript:arretSuivrePortefeuille('13206','Suivre','Arrêter de suivre');">Suivre</a>
```

I receive from FireBug :

> > arretSuivrePortefeuille is not defined
> >     javascript:arretSuivrePortefeuille('13206','Suivre','Arr%C3%AAter%20de%20suivre');()

Any idea?

Comment: You have it... you do not need more...

Comment: @Daok: we don't have `arretSuivrePortefeuille` defined anywhere.

Comment: @Rakesh: please undelete your answer. It is a valuable addition.

Comment: it's not arretSuivrePortefeuille  the problem like I said it works if the parameter doesn't contain a space. otherwise is NOT DEFINED... what ever. It works not, the pboblem was href and onclick... no need to know the function code... like I said before...

Comment: @Daok: allllrighty then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmm, as a first measure remove the `href` attribute and move the instruction into `onclick`, this is the more correct way anyway. Don't forget to remove `onclick` and add a `return false` if necessary. It might be some URL encoding issue present in `href` only.

If that doesn't work out:

- What encoding are you using in the document?
- What encoding are the special characters in?

Comment: Or better yet, remove all inline JavaScript and try being unobtrusive! :)

Comment: I need to call this method with parameter, I do not see how to pass stuff to a function outside the file without passing some info. I will try to do what Pekka suggest, but I do not get J-P comment...

Comment: J-P's comment refers to what CMS is demonstrating in the other answer (bind the event programmatically). This is cleaner because it furhter splits presentation and logic.

Comment: The problem with binding the event programmatically is that both last string in parameter come from the PHP database for the language (website is billingual). How can I do it programmatically in the .JS file when the .PHP require to get those value from the database...

Comment: You could keep the JS code in the main file, but put it into a script tag in the head section. The markup looks cleaner that way. Anyway, it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you at least to use the `onclick` attribute instead of using the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol:

```
<a onclick="arretSuivrePortefeuille('13206','Suivre','Arrêter de suivre');"
   href="#" >Suivre</a>
```

Or better, bind the click event programmatically

```
<a id="linkId" href="#">Suivre</a>
```

---

```
//...
document.getElementById('linkId').onclick = function () {
  arretSuivrePortefeuille('13206','Suivre','Arrêter de suivre');
  return false; // stop link navigation
};
```

Comment: and if CMS is saying so, then you betta do that :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML attributes must have HTML encoding. You might try encoding the special characters in your javascript:

é becomes `&eacute;`
è becomes `&egrave;`
etc.

[Lookuptables](http://www.lookuptables.com/) has a table with a lot of these special characters.

Your line of code will become:

```
<a href="javascript:arretSuivrePortefeuille('13206','Suivre','Arr&ecirc;ter de suivre');">Suivre</a>
```